# Cannot end extrusion along the z axis?

Tags: modeling

I was extruding on the z axis, then attempted to extrude along the x axis. I tried to right click to cancel the z axis extrusion (unsuccessfully). Then right clicked again, to newly select the faces on the x axis to extrude (unsuccessfully). The two arrows, (x,y front view) remained were they were.  I can change the axis constraint, but I can't extrude from a new location and would like to.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your English is too broken to understand. Could you try to write better? And maybe throw in some screenshots? =)

Comment: @Tullerie I'm not sure what you mean by the first bit of the question. About the two arrows, it sounds like you might have the Pivot Center set to 3D Cursor. Try moving the 3D cursor by left clicking or changing the Pivot Center to Bounding Box Center by pressing `,` (comma).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have now tried hitting the comma button, but i don't seem to be having much luck with it.  i will experiment with it a little more.  Thank you.

Comment: @Tullerie  you need to read these posts and update you question :  [how_to_upload_images](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/176/5113)  and  [how_to_upload_blend_file](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file/659#659)

Comment: @Tullerie you have mirror modifier with clipping option checked, uncheck this option and you'll be able to move on XY

Comment: I have a mirror modifier, , but the clipping is not checked.  Although, the Merge and Vertex are checked.

Comment: @Tullerie do you have snapping  or merge limit too high , if you can upload the file it will be easier

Comment: I tried to upload my file twice, but to no avail.  I don't know where it is going.  i copied the URL at this question, and pasted it at Blend-Exchange, then pressed upload. It is in the abyss!   I will look into the snapping or merge limit.  For that I am not sure.  It may take a little while as I am very very new to this.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: My merge limit is .001

Comment: @Tullerie then it's not the merge limit

Comment: Transform snap is turned off.  Is that what i would be concerned with?

Comment: The file is there!

Comment: @Tullerie the file seems good no problem i can extrude on XY , can you move the vertices on the XY

Comment: I am trying to extrude from the right arm.  I had been extruding from the bottom of the T.  It won't seem to move the extruding from the bottom of the T.  i am sure the file is fine, and it is a user error.  I am just not sure what the error is.  Also, I am not sure what you mean when you say extruding on xy.

Comment: @Tullerie I mean i can extrude and move on x or y axis , tell me how you are extruding exactly ( select a vertex , press ....)

Comment: If I left click on the white circle with the blue and red arrow at the bottom of the "T", that will cause the shape to morph.  Then if i right click to "set the shape, and right click again (at the right tip of the "T" then press E, the bottom where the blue and red arrow are morphs.  Is that clear?

Comment: @Tullerie you select one vertex with right_click , press E , move the cursor, left click,  try this on the vertex with the problem and tell me where it went wrong

Comment: When I select the first vertex with a right click (where the blue and red arrows are). then press E, the shape morphs.  I have tried, a left click then E - Right double click then E - left double click then E - all end with the shape distorting from the bottom by the blue/red cursor.  So it always seems to go wrong when I hit E.

Comment: I think i will go back to the very beginning again.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Tullerie the shape will change as you extrude , that's how it's supposed to go

Comment: Yes, but the extrusion changes from where the cross hairs are.  I can't get the crosshairs to move.  Hence, i can only extrude from one place, and not end the extrusion.

Comment: I redid the mesh, and what worked, that did not seem to work last time is to left click to set, then the command like you said, then right click at the point to start the new transformation.  Thank you again for all of your help and perseverance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel an axis constraint, such as the Z axis, hit the same axis key two more times and that will remove the constraint. You can then hit another axis key for another constraint.